# Why is reinitializing a variable out of method in class is an error? Why cant compiler just read and reassign the value to it?

Tags: java

Like here why reinitializing variable i is an error?

```
class deleteme
{
        int i=5;
        i=33;
        public static void main(String args[])
        {

        }
}
```

Comment: The answer is simple: because that is not the grammar of the language. You cannot do arbitrary operations at the class level. At what time would you expect such an operation to be executed? The only logical time is at the time of the object's construction. In which case, put your code in a constructor (though begs the question why wouldn't just initialise it to 33 in the first place).

Answer (score 1):

```
i=33;
```

This is what is called an [`ExpressionStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-14.html#jls-ExpressionStatement) (*).

This is a type of [`Statement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-14.html#jls-Statement).

`Statement`s can only occur inside a [`Block`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-14.html#jls-Block) (although `Block`s can occur inside `Statement`s).

A class declaration isn't a `Block`, so you can't use a `Statement` there, unless you wrap it in a block (e.g. a method body or an initializer).

The only things that can occur directly inside a [`ClassBody`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-8.html#jls-ClassBodyDeclaration) are:

```
ClassBody:
  { {ClassBodyDeclaration} }

ClassBodyDeclaration:
  ClassMemberDeclaration
  InstanceInitializer
  StaticInitializer
  ConstructorDeclaration

ClassMemberDeclaration:
  FieldDeclaration
  MethodDeclaration
  ClassDeclaration
  InterfaceDeclaration
```

---

(*) Actually it's not anything, because it's not valid syntax. If exactly the same line occurred inside a `Block`, it would be an `ExpressionStatement`.

---

The philosophical distinction between the two lines:

```
    int i=5;
    i=33;
```

is that the first is "declaring" something, whereas the second is "doing" something. You can only "do" inside a block.